# El error de TextInputLayout no funciona de la forma deseada

Tags: java, android

Tengo dos `linearLayout` que tienen como hijos a 3 `TextInputEditText` con su respectivo `TextInputLayout`, dejo el código abajo.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_first_column"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/linear_layout_second_column"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/param_1_container"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/param_1_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
                tools:text="TextInputEditText"
                tools:hint="hint"
                />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/param_2_container"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/param_2_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="TextInputEditText"
                tools:hint="hint"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!--  Mount Point Label -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/param_3_container"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/param_3_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="TextInputEditText"
                tools:hint="hint"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_second_column"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_medium"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/linear_layout_first_column"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <!--  UserName Label -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/param_4_container"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/param_4_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="TextInputEditText"
                tools:hint="hint"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <!--  Password Label -->
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/param_5_container"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/param_5_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="TextInputEditText"
                tools:hint="hint"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/param_6_container"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:errorEnabled="true">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/param_6_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:text="TextInputEditText"
                tools:hint="hint"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

El problema reside al darle como error al `TextInputLayout` un texto que no es demasiado largo pero a pesar de eso se tiene que mostrar en 2 líneas, al suceder esto las vistas se corren de posición, esto tiene sentido porque ha crecido el `padding` de la vista pero evidentemente no es muy agradable, dejo imagen sin error y con el error.

### Sin error

[image: sin error]

### Con error

[image: con error]

Existe alguna forma que no sea poner el texto mas pequeño o cambiarlo de tamaño para no obtener este efecto?

Por cierto cabe destacar que he probado aumentando el `margin` y el `padding` de la vista y no funciona

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por fin he encontrado una buena solución después de intentar muchas opciones diferentes.

Me di cuenta que lo que necesitaba era obtener acceso al `TextView` del error, mediante código heredando de `TextInputLayout` era imposible ya que `IndicatorViewController` es privado y es el encargado de trabajar con el error, entonces encontré la siguiente [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48952311/16606928) así que añadiendo el siguiente código todo se soluciona.

```
TextView textView = textInputLayout.findViewById(R.id.textinput_error);
textView.setMaxLines(1);
textView.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
//o también
//textView.setLines(2);
//para que siempre aparezca corrida la vista
```

También podríamos crear una vista personalizada y jugar con este `TexView` para conseguir el efecto que queramos.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo lo que deseas, en este caso desgraciadamente no existe una propiedad o método en el `TextInputLayout` para evitar que la vista muestre un cambio de posición, ya que esto se realiza automáticamente al mostrar el texto del error.

La única opción es realizar un control personalizado similar, puedes revisar este [ejemplo realizado por Ferdous Ahamed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45012947/250260)

[image: jorgesys TextInputLayout]